# error TS2351: This expression is not constructable. Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures

Tags: angular, jspdf

I want to convert html file to pdf file in my project, but I got an error, how can I fix my problem?

```
npm install jspdf
```

DownloadCvCompanent.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-download-cv',
  templateUrl: './download-cv.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download-cv.component.scss']
})
export class DownloadCvComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  @ViewChild('htmlData') htmlData:ElementRef;
  USERS = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",
      "email": "sincere@april.biz",
      "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "email": "shanna@melissa.tv",
      "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Clementine Bauch",
      "email": "nathan@yesenia.net",
      "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
      "email": "julianne@kory.org",
      "phone": "493-170-9623 x156"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
      "email": "lucio@annie.ca",
      "phone": "(254)954-1289"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Mrs. Dennis",
      "email": "karley@jasper.info",
      "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430"
    }
  ];
  public openPDF():void {
    let DATA = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
    let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4');
    doc.fromHTML(DATA.innerHTML,15,15);
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
  }
  public downloadPDF():void {
    let DATA = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
    let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4');
    let handleElement = {
      '#editor':function(element,renderer){
        return true;
      }
    };    
    doc.fromHTML(DATA.innerHTML,15,15,{
      'width': 200,
      'elementHandlers': handleElement
    });
    doc.save('angular-demo.pdf');
  }

}
```

DownloadCvCompanent.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8" id="htmlData" #htmlData>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr class="table-primary">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of USERS">
                    <th>{{user.id}}</th>
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="openPDF()">Open PDF</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" (click)="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

error in terminal:

```
ERROR in src/app/layout/home/download-cv/download-cv.component.ts:57:19 - error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures.

57     let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4');
                     ~~~~~
src/app/layout/home/download-cv/download-cv.component.ts:66:19 - error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures.

66     let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4');
```

error in console (after click button Download PDF;

```
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: jspdf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a constructor
    at DownloadCvComponent.downloadPDF (download-cv.component.ts:66)
    at DownloadCvComponent_Template_button_click_18_listener (download-cv.component.html:23)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21860)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21902)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:976)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41686)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
```

package.json:

```
 { 
   ...
    "jspdf": "^2.3.0",
   ...
 }
```

**How do I fix my problem?**

Comment: The library seems to have plenty of [docs](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/). You should start reading them.

Answer (score 5):

you should use this to import the library:

```
    import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'
```

**important!** using this ES6 syntax you don't need to import the library via the script section in `angular.json`

Next, you need to use the `callback` function to show or download the pdf file:

```js
  public openPDF():void {
    let data = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
    
    let options : any = {
      orientation: 'p',
      unit: 'px',
      format: 'a4',
      };
    let doc = new jsPDF(options);
    doc.html(data.innerHTML, {
      callback: function (doc) {
            doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
          },
      margin:15,
      x: 10,
      y: 10
    });
    
  }
  public downloadPDF():void {
    let data = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
    let options : any = {
      orientation: 'p',
      unit: 'px',
      format: 'a4',
      };
    let doc = new jsPDF(options);
     doc.html(data.innerHTML, {
      callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save("angular-demo.pdf");
          },
      margin:15,
      x: 10,
      y: 10
    });
  }
```

**[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yi8kez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**UPDATE:**

- The `fromHTML` function was replaced by `html` in 2.0.0. amoung other breaking changes that you should be aware if you are migrating from 1.xx to 2.xx

Comment: `import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf'` solve error but gives `doc.fromHTML is not a function` error, any idea/solution?

Comment: The `fromHTML` function was replaced by `HTML` in 2.0.0. Unfortunately, the typings currently still contain the `fromHTML`

Comment: Example - `const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'); doc.html(htmlData.innerHTML, { callback(data:any): void { data.save(); }, x: 10, y: 10 });`

Answer (score 1):

Below solution is working absolutely fine for me and
this works even if you have images in your html.
Create instance of **jspdf** instead of **jsPDF** and used **html()** method instead of **fromHTML().**

```
**Import statement:**
import  jspdf from 'jspdf';

@ViewChild('htmlData', {static: false}) htmlData:ElementRef;

downloadPDF(){
let DATA = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
let PDF = new jspdf('p', 'px', 'a2');
PDF.html(DATA, {
  callback: function(doc){
    doc.save('angular-demo.pdf');
  },
  margin:15,
  x: 10,
  y: 10
});
}
```